# codeigniter controllers .php not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, deployment

I am using the CI default `.htaccess` and the CI dynamic `base_url()`.

My issue is that I have the [deploy.php](https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044) in the controllers folder but when I try and access via `www.domain.com/deploy.php` I get 404 not found why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter controllers are accessed like that `www.domain.com/deploy`(by class name in lower case, file name must match classname inside in lower case and class must extend `CI_Controller`)

The file you mention is nothing like that, so it is better to be called from the folder where `index.php` resides.